# Generating 3-byte (0x800 to 0xffff) UTF-8 encodings in Java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to generate a random string of Unicode characters. I want to specify the number of bytes each character takes (1-4 bytes since I want to convert them eventually to a UTF-8 byte array), as well as the number of characters. For example, if I specify 10 as the number of characters in my string and 3 as the bytes per character, I should get a string str and when I call

```
str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length
```

I should get 30 bytes.

My code generates the correct string for characters using 1, 2, and 4 bytes. However, For code points from 0x800 to 0xffff, when I call getBytes on the returned string, I get a different number of bytes each time. Any ideas why this may be happening?

```
private String generateRandomString(int numberOfCharacters, int bytesPerCharacter) {

        int start;
        int end;

        switch (bytesPerCharacter) {
            case 1:
                start = 0;
                end = 0x7f;
                break;
            case 2:
                start = 0x80;
                end = 0x7ff;
                break;
            case 3:
                start = 0x800;
                end = 0xffff;
                break;
            case 4:
                start = 0x10000;
                end = 0x10ffff;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value for the bytes per character");
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(numberOfCharacters);
        int count = 0;
        int range = end - start;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharacters; i++) {
            builder.appendCodePoint((int) (Math.random() * range + start));
        }
        return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: it's non-deterministic - if you try with a high numberOfCharacters (above 200) I usually can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question

## TL; DR

The answer is that some of the generated code points are not valid Unicode, and Java knows this, replacing them with `?` when encoding as UTF-8, which throws off the count, as only one byte is output for those code points, instead of three.

## Explanation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int start = 0x800;
    int end   = 0xffff;
    int range = end-start;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        int a = (int)(Math.random() * range + start);
        b.appendCodePoint(a);
        System.out.printf("Code point %5d length=%d\n", a, b.length());
    }
    byte[] result = b.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(result.length);
    for (byte x : result)
    {
        // newline before any byte matching 1110 xxxx (start of 3-byte UTF-8)
        if ((x & 0xF0) == 0xE0) System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%02x ", x);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

On some runs this produces less than 60 bytes out, for example this one:

```
Code point 35798 length=1
Code point 30523 length=2
Code point 43674 length=3
Code point  2743 length=4
Code point 64416 length=5
Code point  2438 length=6
Code point 15808 length=7
Code point 56254 length=8
Code point 20690 length=9
Code point 48789 length=10
Code point 52635 length=11
Code point  9128 length=12
Code point  8445 length=13
Code point 27765 length=14
Code point 63710 length=15
Code point 53350 length=16
Code point 41031 length=17
Code point 25939 length=18
Code point 56414 length=19
Code point 46327 length=20
56

e8 af 96 
e7 9c bb 
ea aa 9a 
e0 aa b7 
ef ae a0 
e0 a6 86 
e3 b7 80 3f 
e5 83 92 
eb ba 95 
ec b6 9b 
e2 8e a8 
e2 83 bd 
e6 b1 b5 
ef a3 9e 
ed 81 a6 
ea 81 87 
e6 95 93 3f 
eb 93 b7
```

Note there are only 18 lines in the hex dump of the UTF-8, and `0x3f = ?`.  Looking up the generated "code points" in the 8th and 19th positions reveals that these are invalid Unicode code points.

- Code point [56254](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/56254/index.htm)
- Code point [56414](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/dc5e/index.htm)

## Conclusion

You cannot generate random integer values and expect all of them to be valid Unicode.  Encoding a `String` containing such code points will encode the invalid code points as `0x3f` (`'?'`).

Comment: In the U+0800 - U+FFFF range of codepoints, watch out for U+D800 - U+DFFF, which are reserved and should NEVER appear in a Unicode string.  And also U+E000 - U+F8FF, which are private-use codepoints. Once you get above U+FFFF, there are a LOT of private-use/unallocated codepoints. In any case, you could always just skip using `getBytes(UTF8)` and encode the codepoints manually, even if they are not "legal". UTF-8 is very easy to implement by handle, and it is only concerned about encoding bits, it doesn't care what the actual codepoint values are other than for grouping bits.